# How to recover from missing revisions when using an incremental svn backup strategy

Tags: svn, backup, svnadmin

I'm currently using an incremental backup method for an SVN repository, where I make a separate dump for each revision that's not dumped yet. This seems to work well and keeps backups manageable.

My question is, can I restore the repository when one of the revisions is missing? For example, because 1 file in the backups got corrupt. This has not happened yet, but I don't want unpleasant surprises later.

For reference, I use this script:

```
REVISION=$(svn info <svnurl> | sed -ne 's/^Revision: //p')

for i in $(seq 0 $REVISION); do
        if [[ ! -f repobackup-$(printf %07d ${i}).svndump.gz ]]; then
                svnadmin dump /path/to/repo -r ${i} --incremental -q | gzip > repobackup-$(printf %07d ${i}).svndump.gz
        fi
done
```